# How to structure component export without export default?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying not to use `export default` in my components but rather `export function..`

My components are structured something like this:

```
function Hero(props) {
  return (
    <section className="hero">
        <div className="wrapper">
            <div className="content">
                <h1>{props.title}</h1>
                <p>{props.text}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
);
}

export default Hero;
```

when I do `import {Hero} from './components/hero/hero.js'` it works ok for this component, however if I have a component that is receiving props. Like this, it does not work:

```
export function Chart() {
    return (
        <section className="chart">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <h2>{this.props.children}</h2>
                <div className="img-container">
                    <img className="desktop" src={chart} />
                    <img className="mobile" src={mobileChart} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

I am trying to avoid `export default` and avoid using something like

```
class Chart extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <section className="chart">
                <div className="wrapper">
                    <h2>{this.props.children}</h2>
                    <div className="img-container">
                        <img className="desktop" src={chart} alt="Mortgage Rate Comparison Chart"/>
                        <img className="mobile" src={mobileChart} alt="Mortgage Rate Comparison Chart"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default Chart;
```

When I try to switch this I am getting an error, i'm not sure the proper syntax for exporting this way. It was a request made by my lead dev and he is out of office this week.

Comment: how do you import the function?

Comment: I am importing it like import {hero} from '../components/hero.js' 

These ones are ok. The issue is when I have a function that is taking {children.props} i'll update my answer to explain more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have one model per module, default exports are preferred as per [ECMAScript](http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html#default-exports-one-per-module)

If your code is like this in the file:

**ChartComponent.js**

```
export function Chart(props) {
    return (
        <section className="chart">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <h2>{props.children}</h2>
                <div className="img-container">
                    <img className="desktop" src={chart} />
                    <img className="mobile" src={mobileChart} />
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    );
}
```

You have to import it this way:

**With export default**

```
import Chart from "./ChartComponent";
```

**Without export default**

```
import { Chart } from "./ChartComponent";


<Chart>
  <div>
    child elements
  </div>
</Chart>
```

This should pass the children into your component if you are listening for props.

---

If you have multiple components in single file, you can export them in these ways:

ExampleMultipleComponents.js

```
export const ComponentI = class ComponentI extends React.Component {....};
export const ComponentII = () => (<div> ... </div>);
```

or like:

```
const ComponentI = class ComponentI extends React.Component {....};
const ComponentII = () => (<div> ... </div>);

export {
  ComponentII,
  ComponentI,
}
```

And them import them like:

```
import { ComponentI, ComponentII } from './ExampleMultipleComponents';
```

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: My file structure is pretty flat. Just 1 file per component. I am trying to avoid export default for class components I guess?